# EntityFramework Core Fluent Model Builder Key and Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, fluent, fluent-entity-framework

Ok so in entity framework 6 I would have had a key and property database generation in one statement:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Function>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

In entity framework core (7) this does not work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Function>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

*Error: "'KeyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Property' and no extension method 'Property' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyBuilder'":*

**Does this have to be two separate statements as below or is there a way to have it in one like you could in EF6?**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Function>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Function>()
                    .Property(x => x.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are separate in EF Core.

The reason is because EF6 method allows you to specify the PK columns and nothing more, hence is returning `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType>` (the same as the target obtained from `Entity<...>` call) and that's why you can continue fluently configuring the entity type.

However the EF Core method returns a different type called `KeyBuilder` which allows you to further configure the PK, like `HasName` for the relational constraint name, or specific database attributes like `ForSqlServerHasName` and `ForSqlServerIsClustered` etc.